# Help needed in determining if statement is true

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $H$ with $x_n\rightharpoonup x\in H$ weakly. Then $\|x_n\|\to\|x\|$.

I found this in one of my textbook; my question is if this statement is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. If $\{ e_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal sequence in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, then this sequence converges weakly to $0$ because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(x,e_n)|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}$ for all $x$, which forces the general term of the sum to converge to $0$.

If $\{ x_n \}$ converges weakly to $x$ and $\{ \|x_n\| \}$ converges to $\|x\|$, then $\{ x_n \}$ converges strongly to $x$ because
$$
\begin{align}
     \|x_n-x\|^{2} & =\|x_n\|^{2}-(x_n,x)-(x,x_n)+\|x\|^{2} \\
       & \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathcal{L}^2([0,2\pi])$, the functions $x \mapsto \sin(nx)$ converge weakly to 0. However their $\mathcal{L}^2$ are all the same.  Your conjecture does not hold.